# how to clear status entries

Tags: git, github

I staged a bunch of files but then deleted them before committing to by repository. When I do a `git status` I see this:

```
# deleted: filename.fileext
```

I have been able to commit new changes but these deleted files are still appearing in the status check. Can someone explain why? How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git add -u
git commit -m "Deleted files manually"
```

Comment: see git add help:

Only match <filepattern> against already tracked files in the index rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the corresponding files in the working tree have been removed. 

If no <filepattern> is given, default to "."; in other words, update all tracked files in the current directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `rm` command to remove files, run `git rm <file_path_to_be_removed>` to tell git that these files are deleted.

`rm` command only removes physical files. Then you need to notify git.

```
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ touch a.txt
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git add a.txt
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git commit -m"m"
[master (root-commit) 03f6743] m
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git status 
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ rm a.txt 
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    a.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git rm a.txt
rm 'a.txt'
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    a.txt
#
kevin@kevin-dev:/tmp/git$
```

The tow `deleted` status are **different**. The first one is **Changes not staged for commit:**, second is **Changes to be committed:**
So, just run `git commimt -m"Message"`, and then everything is clean.

Comment: I did this but the files are still appearing as `deleted` when I run `git status`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: don't forgot to commit after !